# How to fit IMG size into JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm kinda doing a GUI where when you press the "NEXT" button, it shows one by one the images at some directory.

My question is: How can I fit the size of the IMGs with the JPanles dimensions, I'm working with 6 or more MP images and I need to see the entire image.

Here is the code that gives me the imageIcon and where I add it to the JPanel.

```
JButton btnNextImg = new JButton("Next IMG");
    btnNextImg.setBounds(96, 179, 110, 23);
    btnNextImg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (i == nImg)
                i = 0;
            try {
                selectedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\IMAGES\\"+ String.valueOf(i+1) + ".jpg"));
                iSelect = new ImageIcon(selectedImage);
                originalImage.setIcon(iSelect);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnNextImg);
```

And where I add it.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    originalImage = new JLabel();
    panel.add(originalImage);
    panel.setBounds(5, 226, 309, 280);
    contentPane.add(panel);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how you can expand or shrink the image file to either fill the entire panel's view, and have the image be fully viewable in the panel's view?

Comment: Yes, I need to shrink it so it can be fully viewed in the panel's view. Like a preview of the image, a thumbnail.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ImageIcon, but I'd imagine the graphics would stretch to fill its entire container with some constructor option? If not, you can scale the image before you pass it in, or make a custom JComponent which draws and stretches to the component's width and height.

Comment: My problem is that I'm too noob at programming GUI's @NESPowerGlove & programming in general. Could you show some example code of what you're talking about? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Ah okay. If you know Java and would like to know more about Swing, then I would recommend the book Filthy Rich Clients, or Swing tutorial on Oracle's site.

Answer (score 1):

here's an image panel i found somewhere on the internet when i had the same problem:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

private java.awt.Image image;
private boolean stretched = true;
private int xCoordinate;
private int yCoordinate;

public ImagePanel() {

}

public ImagePanel(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (image != null) {
        if (isStretched()) {
            g.drawImage(image, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, this);
        }
    }
}

public java.awt.Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(java.awt.Image image) {
    this.image = image;
    repaint();
}

public boolean isStretched() {
    return stretched;
}

public void setStretched(boolean stretched) {
    this.stretched = stretched;
    repaint();
}

public int getXCoordinate() {
    return xCoordinate;
}

public void setXCoodinate(int xCoordinate) {
    this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
}

public int getYCoordinate() {
    return xCoordinate;
}

public void setYCoordinate(int yCoordinate) {
    this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    repaint();
}
}
```

to add an image to the panel use something like this:

```
ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\IMAGES\\"+ String.valueOf(i+1) + ".jpg"));
imagePanel.setImage(image);
```

Comment: Yes, I did also found that one but it just doesn't fit with my code. I'm using imageIOread and in that code is using other way of handling with images.

Comment: I edited my answer. I wrote a little example. Instead of creating a label as in your code, just add the image of ImageIO.read to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code that gives me the imageIcon and where I add it to the JPanel.

Check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). It will allow the Icon to fill the entire space available to the JLabel.